# learning how to use cURL

Tags: curl

I am learning how to use the cURL command and had a question, when I run the command on one site I get data, however when I run it on another I just get a response of [].  The response code for the second site is 200 OK, does the [] mean there is not data there?  thanks

Comment: Yep, it means that this is what the other site responded with to your request.

Comment: Thanks sergio, so there is some issue with the device that is supposed to be sending the data to the url?